# Design pattern tracking method calls/callers

Tags: c#, logging, architecture, method-call

I don't know what to do in a specific software designing situation. Just searched the internet for solution, but did not find a satisfying answer. So i just want to know your expertise and what the best pratice would be.
I have got a system with several layers of abstraction to begin with. The API shown to the user is a simple class with a compact number of methods. Calling those methods will trigger a avalanche of method calls all the way through the whole abstraction. Certain decissions will be made along the way. Each element on this way can send there decissions and reasons for that decissions via a messageing system back to whoever wants to read it. The system is also logging all the calls and the decissions, which is quite important - well rather the most important. To be honest that is the core issue.

The problem is: I want to know WHO called a certain Method. So i can hand some kind of handle down the way and every abstraction knows: "Right, this guy wants that. So i can log: This guy wanted that."

Why i believe i need this is, because different other systems will be able to use that api. Maybe a GUI wants to drop a command, maybe a HTTP driven remote controller, maybe a hardware trigger, maybe an auto executing routine.

I don't want to let the system make decissions basing on WHO called. I know that would be the absolute opposite of what i intended in abstracting all thouse layers. I just want to log properly. WHO wanted to do WHAT.

Right now i just cannot see the wood for the trees. I just let hand out the API a ticket like object instance. The system is registering that ticket with a id. The API users have to hand in the ticket when calling a command so the system knows who just called.

Well, to put the question to single sentence:
**Is there a good pattern for tracking/identifying the caller of a method?**

edit:
Altough it is a general problem the used language in this situation is c#!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `[CallerMemberName]` attribute:

```
public void SomeMethod(string name, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = null)
{
    Console.Writeline($"SomeMethod was called from {callerName}");
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. While this just let me know the member name it is a good step to begin with. Especially because it does not need any further conditions. Just adding those words... Quite nice.
Still the problem would be: Gui calling via method QWERTYCallMethod and by pure accident the same method is used to call the api from the web-controller.

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is working like a charm... So far. But i would like to know if it would be considered bad practice or if you might see a bottleneck jsut form the first glance.

```
    //< API user will call this kind of method handing in their requested Accessor!
    public void Command( int a, int b, KomiAccessorBase accessor=null ){
        if( !AccessGranted( accessor ) ) return;
        this.SubController.CommandA( a, b , accessor );
    }

    //< Accessor is checked on validity
    private bool AccessGranted(KomiAccessorBase accessor, [CallerMemberName] string callerName = null ) {
        if (accessor == null) {
            log("KOMI - Access to ["+callerName+"] denied: No Accessor handed in!", MsgType.LOG);
            return false;
        }
        if ( !_kacc_inventory.ContainsKey(accessor.KACCHashId)) {
            log("KOMI - Access to [" + callerName + "] denied: Accessor not registered in KOMI!", MsgType.LOG);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    protected Dictionary<int, KomiAccessorBase> _kacc_inventory = new Dictionary<int, KomiAccessorBase>();

    //< The Accessor base class. API user have to derive from that!
    public abstract class KomiAccessorBase : RecieverBase, INameable {
        public int KACCHashId { get; private set; }
        private string _name;
        public string Name {
            get {
                return _name;
            }
            private set {

            }
        }
        protected KomiAccessorBase(string name, KOMI komi) : base(komi.Office) {
            Name = name;
            KACCHashId = -1;
            KACCHashId = komi.RegisterAccessor(this); //Perform the real registration
        }
    }

    //< Registeres the Accessor on KOMI for access checking!
    public int RegisterAccessor(KomiAccessorBase acc) {
        if (acc.KACCHashId != -1) return -1; //Abbort registration if already registered!
        int salt = 1;
        int hashId = (salt + "#" + acc.Name).GetHashCode();
        while (_kacc_inventory.ContainsKey(hashId)) {
            salt++;
            hashId = (salt + "#" + acc.Name).GetHashCode();
        }
        _kacc_inventory.Add(hashId, acc);
        return hashId;
    }
```